# Node data update d3.js v4 force diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Say we have a force diagram of 4 interlinked nodes (how they linked dont matter for this situation):

```
{name: A, age: 15}
{name: B, age: 5}
{name: C, age: 4}
{name: D, age: 66}
```

Now I receive two nodes:

```
{name: E, age: 12}
{name: A, age: 7}
```

I am going to update the graph which is now going to have 5 nodes in total, but I also would like to update the age of matching nodes. So the end result (age) of node A would be 22.

The procedure I'm following is:

```
node = svg             
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.name; });

var nodeEnter = node
                        .enter()
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("class", "node");

                    nodeEnter
                        .append("circle")        
                        .attr("r", 5);
```

So somewhere in here Id like to sum the age property. Any ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously with D3, (before v4) you were not able to compare a node's old and new data values during the update step without storing the data as a javascript property of the DOM object for the element, similar to how [data is stored in D3's **data** property.](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#joining-data)

This process of storing local variables has been made part of the library in v4 with the [d3.local() method.](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local)

The way it works is you declare a local data variable a la 

`var persistedData = d3.local();`

and then, call `persistedData.set(this, d.age);` for each node and call `persistedData.get(this)` to retrieve that previous age data where you are appending the age data to the dom for presentation.

```
nodeEnter
  .append("text")
  .attr("dx", 12)
  .attr("dy", "2em")
  .text(function(d) {
   var oldAge = persistedData.get(this);
   return oldAge ? oldAge + d.age : d.age;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to implement is the General Update Pattern [read more here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218). And you'll need to use key functions on your .data() method. Mike has an example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221). It shouldn't be too hard, let me know if you have some problems.

Comment: Right, Im probably missing something here. I have an update logic thats not the problem. And I cant see how Mike is accessing old data properties when binding with new data

Comment: you set the key function, so your selection knows how to identify your data. You'll have to access the old data outside of d3. Do the processing then, feed the data into your update function. Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: Surely I can access existing data's properties (age) during the update/merge and not do it outside. I think I have explained the problem pretty well: If the nodes match, the new node's age property is going to be  old_node.age + new_node.age. It could also be that I'm not following what youre trying to suggest, so my apologies